# What IRC / web chats / Slack chat channels are there for Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Are there any online chat channels for discussing Nativescript development, such as IRC e.g. FreeNode, Slack, or any other chats?

There is a #Nativescript channel on FreeNode IRC however it has only two members, so I thought there may be some other channel.

Thanks again for your fantastic work!

Answer (score 1):

There is a NativeScript Slack Community:

- [nativescriptcommunity.slack.com](https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com/)

There is also the forums (discourse)

- [discourse.nativescript.org](http://discourse.nativescript.org)